How to do gradient masking in Figma
I have followed the YouTube tutorials exactly as they explained but still not solving my problem. I am very new to Figma so I am in the process of learning.
As per the tutorials after you place the masking shape below the image and then select the two together and press mask and then press the masking shape (the one with the eclipse shape in the left side under layers) and go on to chose fill then gradient the result is that the image on top will have a gradient effect.
But when I press gradient the image has no gradient effect on it and it stays the same.

When you want a gradient effect on the image, you need to adjust the opacity of the underlying gradient fill to achieve it.

